# How do I print the local and remote address and port of a connected socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a connected socket. When I use:

```
print (mySocket)
```

I get this:

`<socket.socket fd=376, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.31.244', 4160), raddr=('192.168.31.244', 7061)>`

I can also successfully print:

```
print (mySocket.family)
print (mySocket.proto)
```

But if I try to print the address:

```
print(mySocket.laddr)
```

I get and error:

```
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'laddr'
```

How can I print the *laddr* and *raddr* attributes?

Comment: [socket.getsockname()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) and [socket.getpeername()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername)

Comment: For completeness: you can use `dir` to see all attributes for a given object.  So with `print(dir(mySocket))` you'll see that there is no `laddr` or `raddr` attribute, but there is a `getpeername` and `getsockname`.

Comment: Thanks. So what is laddr and raddr considered if not attributes?

Comment: @1qazxsw2 when you print out an object, the things you see aren't necessarily attributes on the object - it can print whatever it wants via the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods. So chances are what's happening is that the object is looking at internal private variables to construct that string representation, but you can't access those variables directly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try using the [`.getsockname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) and [`.getpeername()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername) methods instead. As noted [in the Socket object docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects) only the `family`, `proto`, and `type` fields are available as attributes.

```
>>> s.bind(('localhost',12345))
>>> s.getsockname()
('127.0.0.1', 12345)
```

Comment: When bind socket and accept, `getsockname` is not declared.

Answer (score 18):

For `laddr` use `mySocket.getsockname()` and for `raddr` use `mySocket.getpeername()`