# Printing out addr from Python TCP WebServer

Tags: python, tcpserver

I am able to print out the localhost, 127.0.0.1, just fine but I am having trouble printing out port 61627 as seen below. As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250805/how-do-i-print-the-local-and-remote-address-and-port-of-a-connected-socket), I set `outputdata = serverSocket.getsockname()` and `serverSocket.getpeername()` but both failed to return the port.

```
#import socket module
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print ('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print ('Required connection', addr)

    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        outputdata = addr
        connectionSocket.send(('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n').encode('utf-8'))
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode('utf-8'))

        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send(('404 Not Found').encode('utf-8'))
        connectionSocket.close()
        serverSocket.close()
```

[image]

Comment: For the port used for the single connection for a request, check on ``connectionSocket``, not ``serverSocket``. That for ``serverSocket`` would always be 80, being the listener socket only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the for loop and replaced `connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode('utf-8'))` with `connectionSocket.sendall(str(outputdata).encode('utf-8'))`. I had convert the output data to a string, and the `sendall` returns the entire tuple. The final code for my impromptu Python TCP WebServer is:

```
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print ('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print ('Required connection', addr)

    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        outputdata = addr
        connectionSocket.send(('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n').encode('utf-8'))
        connectionSocket.sendall(str(outputdata).encode('utf-8'))
        print(outputdata)
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send(('404 Not Found').encode('utf-8'))
        connectionSocket.close()
        serverSocket.close()
```

Will return this to the localhost

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering the aforementioned script belongs to server, you may try to add 
`serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` 
before binding