# Can I get the source port of an ssh connection in netmiko/paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, netmiko

I have an application where I configure Cisco Routers in a LAB environment through a Console Server. 
The routers can be reached via SSH. Sometimes after a program exit/crash the ssh connection is not terminated.
After a restart I cannot login to that specific router while the port on the console server is blocked.
To unblock it I need to terminate that ssh session.
If I have more sessions in use I do not know which of them I need to terminate, so I would like to get the source port when the connection was built by paramiko/netmiko.

Did somebody did this before, or maybe somebody has an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Paramiko SSH connection's underlying socket, use `ssh.get_transport().sock`.
Then, see [How do I print the local and remote address and port of a connected socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41250805/850848)

So usually, this will work:

```
port = ssh.get_transport().sock.getsockname()[1]
```

But that makes couple of assumptions. As you do not need to use the port number programatically, safer is to just print the complete result of `getsockname()`, rather than assuming that the result is a tuple with a port at index 1.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.